# edit for formatting gone

Tags: support, specific-question, suggested-edits

I made an edit in [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/368812/why-does-apt-get-upgrade-show-error-grub-efi-amd64-r-base-core-packages-are-no) Question  for formatting. But now I see it is gone.

Did I something wrong?

Comment: it appears to have been rolled back: [Rollback to Revision 1 - Edit approval overridden by post owner or moderator](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/368812/revisions)

Comment: Great, but now it is not readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to me that you did nothing wrong; the owner of the post reverted or rejected your change. I left a note on their post to that effect.